# Jersey not working for POST, PUT

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish, jax-rs

I have a problem which seems to have a simple solution but I haven't been able to solve for months:

I'm trying to POST/PUT JSONs, and having the server recognize and deserialize them as their corresponding classes. But the server is not able to parse the entity, and returns a 500 error code.

This has to do with the fact that the generated code expects an interface (`Apple`) instead of a 'normal' Java class (`AppleImpl`).

I know this because **the methods work if I change the interface (`Apple`) with the implementation (`AppleImpl`) in the endpoint**, since the server detects the type and deserializes it correctly, but it is *tedious and error-prone* to manually change the interfaces to implementations every time that a change is made in the RAML.

In the Java backend, I'm using an entity, interface and endpoint, all of which were generated using [raml-to-jax-rs v3.0.2](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-for-jax-rs). I'm using Maven with Jersey (jersey-bom) v2.27.

To summarize, I would like to know how to successfully **deserialize an *interface* in Jersey/JAX-RS**. Am I missing an annotation, are my Maven package versions wrong, or is it something else?

I would very much appreciate if someone could help me with this, and I will provide more information if necessary. Below is some sample generated code so that the problem is clearer.

---

### Sample generated code:

(1/3) Sample generated interface `Apple`:

```
@JsonDeserialize(
    as = AppleImpl.class
)
public interface Apple {
  @JsonAnyGetter
  Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties();

  @JsonAnySetter
  void setAdditionalProperties(String key, Object value);

  @JsonProperty("name")
  String getName();

  @JsonProperty("name")
  void setName(String name);

  @JsonProperty("values")
  List<String> getValues();

  @JsonProperty("values")
  void setValues(List<String> values);

  @JsonProperty("defaultValue")
  String getDefaultValue();

  @JsonProperty("defaultValue")
  void setDefaultValue(String defaultValue);
}
```

(2/3) Sample generated class `AppleImpl`:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "name",
    "values",
    "defaultValue"
})
public class AppleImpl implements Apple {
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty("values")
  @NotNull
  private List<String> values;

  @JsonProperty("defaultValue")
  @NotNull
  private String defaultValue;

  @JsonIgnore
  private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  @JsonProperty("name")
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  @JsonProperty("name")
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @JsonProperty("values")
  public List<String> getValues() {
    return this.values;
  }

  @JsonProperty("values")
  public void setValues(List<String> values) {
    this.values = values;
  }

  @JsonProperty("defaultValue")
  public String getDefaultValue() {
    return this.defaultValue;
  }

  @JsonProperty("defaultValue")
  public void setDefaultValue(String defaultValue) {
    this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
  }

  @JsonAnyGetter
  public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return additionalProperties;
  }

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setAdditionalProperties(String key, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(key, value);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) return false;
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    AppleImpl other = (AppleImpl) o;
    return java.util.Objects.equals(this.name, other.name) && java.util.Objects.equals(this.values, other.values) && java.util.Objects.equals(this.defaultValue, other.defaultValue) && java.util.Objects.equals(this.additionalProperties, other.additionalProperties);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name,values,defaultValue,additionalProperties);
  }
}
```

(3/3) Sample generated POST endpoint:

```
@Override
public PostApplesResponse postApples(String xSessionToken, Apple bean) {
  try {
    MUser user = AuthUtils.authenticates(xSessionToken);
    ModelMapperApple.get().validateBean(bean);
    MApple entity = ModelMapperApple.get().b2e(bean);
    MApple entityOut = AppleService.getInstance().post(user, entity);
    AppleResponse beanOut = ModelMapperApple.get().e2b(entityOut);
    return PostApplesResponse.respond201WithApplicationJson(beanOut);
  } catch (BadRequestException e) {
    CRUDUtils.logException(e);
    return PostApplesResponse.respond400WithApplicationJson(ErrorMessageUtils.build(e));
  } catch (UnauthorizedException e) {
    CRUDUtils.logException(e);
    return PostApplesResponse.respond401();
  } catch (ConflictException e) {
    CRUDUtils.logException(e);
    return PostApplesResponse.respond409();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    CRUDUtils.logException(e);
    return PostApplesResponse.respond500();
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally I feel using interfaces for model classes is just useless. As far as the deserialization, if Jackson (or whatever provider) sees `Apple`, it's going to try to instantiate an `Apple` as that's all it knows. How is it supposed to know it is supposed to use `AppleImpl`. It's impossible. So as for your question _"how to successfully deserialize an interface in Jersey/JAX-RS"_ - you simple can't

Comment: I agree with you in that I don't see the use, but this is how raml-to-jax-rs generates the JAX-RS code, so there must be a way somehow. The way that the interface is supposed to know what to deserialize into is in the @JsonDeserialize annotation, but it doesn't seem to be working for me or something else is wrong...

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know about that feature of `@JsonDeserialize`. I take my comment back about being impossible then. My guess would be that Jackson is not even being used. If you are in Glassfish, the default provider is MOXy. You need to configure it to use Jackson.

Comment: Or with Glassfish 5, the default provider is JSON-B. Either way, you still need to configure Jersey to use Jackson.

Comment: I am in Glassfish, and the pom does have a `jersey-media-moxy`! But this may be a redundant dependency because the parent pom (this is a multi-module project) has a `jackson-databind` (v2.9.5). And the methods *do* work when I replace the interface with the implementation, so Jackson should be working, I think.

Comment: Glassfish already has all those Jars, whether you include them or not in the final artifact. You _should_ put them all as a provided scope though so you don't mix version with the Jars that Glassfish already has. My point is that Without any further configuration of the JSON Provider, MOXy will be used, whether or not you have it as a dependency. If you want to use Jackson, you should add the `jersey-media-json-jackson` dependency, and register the `JacksonFeature` with your application.

Comment: OK, thanks Paul, I will try configuring the JSON Provider as you have said. I'll let you know if I get it to work, but it seems like a great lead.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Thanks for checking back; I managed to switch from MOXy to Jackson but I have not been able to make it behave correctly with Jersey. I'm not sure if it's a package conflict issue. I will let you know when I figure it out :)